# Bases de datos, relaciones tabla intermedia

Tags: php, mysql, sql

primero que todo no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre MySQL, ni bases de datos en general, así que lamento las molestias que pueda ocasionar.

Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas, registrado, y producto, registrado tiene atributos como ID (clave primaria), el usuario registrado, su contraseña y su email, por otra parte la tabla productos tiene otro atributo ID (clave primaria), el nombre del producto, el precio y una breve descripción del mismo.

Lo que me interesa es tener una tabla intermedia dónde pueda almacenar UNICAMENTE, el nombre de usuario y el respectivo precio.

Tal que:

```
Juan 200
Pablo 129
Juan 19
Raquel 15
```

Es decir, un nombre puede aparecer en varias ocasiones.

Ahora bien, ¿qué necesitaria en la tabla intermedia, y con qué lo podría relacionar? este es el principal problema.

Por último, si en la tabla intermedia quisiera introducir datos mediante PDO de PHP, sería tan sencillo como mandar un query que haga un insert into a esa tabla ¿verdad?

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Puedes explicar un pocomas o mejor que es lo que realmente necesitas, o que es lo que pretendes hacer, es decir, nos puedes explicar los requerimientos. De esta forma te podremos ayudar a determinar si realmente necesitas una tabla intermedia y cuales serian sus relaciones. No me queda claro que determina el precio y las relaciones directas entre usuario y producto.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que comentas, según mi experiencia, no es posible. Debes relacionarla con algún campo.

Aunque sea un campo id.

Ejemplo:

Tabla Intermedia:

```
id int auto incremental primary_key
usuario text
valor int
id_usuario int
id_producto int
```

Query:

```
SELECT usuario, valor FROM intermedia WHERE id_usuario = x OR id_producto = x
```

Podrías mejorar aún más la tabla prescindiendo de los campos usuario y valor, ya que con los id de registrado y productos tienes estos datos en sus respectivas tablas, si es así como lo tienes claro...

Consulta:

```
SELECT registrados.nombre, productos.valor FROM intermedia INNER JOIN registrados ON registrados.id = intermedia.usuario_id INNER JOIN productos ON productos.id = intermedia.producto_id WHERE registrados.id = x
```

A partir del WHERE ya es cuestión de lo que necesites... como si prescindes de él y te devolverá todos los resultados relacionando las dos tablas, productos y registrados.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿y como relacionaria con esa tabla teniendo dicho campo ID? quiero decir, vale, el ID de la tabla Registrado, con el ID de la tabla intermedia, ¿pero y el otro ID de la tabla productoscon que lo relaciono en la tabla intermedia?

Comment: Creas dos campos en la tabla intermedia, uno guarda el id de registrado y el otro el id de productos. Luego al hacer la query llamas los datos según tus necesidades. Actualizo post principal con algún ejemplo.